# No se me visualiza las capas KML que quiero implementar en mi sitio por medio de Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

Lo que quiero es que al apretar en un check aparezca la capa KML con todos sus datos. Este código lo saqué [aquí](https://codepen.io/royce002/pen/JRLJXO).
Pero no se me visualiza y además me sale un error en la consola "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

```
<script>
    var map;

    // lets define some vars to make things easier later
    var kml = {
        a: {
            name: "MPLS/STPL",
            url: "https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=5&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=212971981154994583939.0004b06640255267e038c"
        },
        b: {
            name: "Bicycling Tour Routes",
            url: "https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=4&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=212971981154994583939.0004902a1824bbc8c0fe9"
        },
        c: {
            name: "areas verdes",
            url: "kml/areas_verdes.kml"
        }
        // keep adding more if ye like 
    };


    // initialize our goo
    function initializeMap() {
        var options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.4488897, -70.6692655),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);
        createTogglers();
    };
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);

    // the important function... kml[id].xxxxx refers back to the top 
    function toggleKML(checked, id) {

        if (checked) {

            var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kml[id].url, {
                preserveViewport: true,
                suppressInfoWindows: true
            });
            // store kml as obj
            kml[id].obj = layer;
            kml[id].obj.setMap(map);
        } else {
            kml[id].obj.setMap(null);
            delete kml[id].obj;
        }

    };

    // create the controls dynamically because it's easier, really
    function createTogglers() {

        var html = "<form><ul>";
        for (var prop in kml) {
            html += "<li id=\"selector-" + prop + "\"><input type='checkbox' id='" + prop + "'" +
                " onclick='highlight(this,\"selector-" + prop + "\"); toggleKML(this.checked, this.id)' \/>" +
                kml[prop].name + "<\/li>";
        }
        html += "<li class='control'><a href='#' onclick='removeAll();return false;'>" +
            "Remove all layers<\/a><\/li>" +
            "<\/ul><\/form>";

        document.getElementById("toggle_box").innerHTML = html;
    };

    // easy way to remove all objects
    function removeAll() {
        for (var prop in kml) {
            if (kml[prop].obj) {
                kml[prop].obj.setMap(null);
                delete kml[prop].obj;
            }

        }
    };

    // Append Class on Select
    function highlight(box, listitem) {
        var selected = 'selected';
        var normal = 'normal';
        document.getElementById(listitem).className = (box.checked ? selected : normal);
    };

    function startup() {
        // for example, this toggles kml b on load and updates the menu selector
        var checkit = document.getElementById('b');
        checkit.checked = true;
        toggleKML(checkit, 'b');
        highlight(checkit, 'selector1');
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        startup();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Por favor, dale a [edit] para añadir más información a tu pregunta: ¿qué hace ese código? ¿Te sale algún error en la consola? ¿Qué has intentado? Las preguntas que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad porque no presentan un problema claro. Lee [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios problemas.

1. Al parecer no estás cargando jQuery en tu documento. (Por otro lado, no debieras necesitarlo)
2. Declaras la variable global `map` y luego dentro de la función `initializeMap` la redeclaras. Esto se llama shadowing y afecta a la variable en el contexto de la función, pero la global map sigue inalterada y tiene valor `undefined`. Luego cuando hacer `layer.setMap(map)` no le estás pasando realmente el valor de tu instancia de mapa. Quita el `var` al instanciar el mapa.
3. La url relativa de tu tercer elemento no es visible para google maps. Tiene que ser un archivo públicamente visible para que google lo parsee y lo devuelva como un layer. Debieras poner la url absoluta de tu kml.
4. Aunque tuvieras jQuery cargado, al llamar a `startup` antes de que existan los checkboxes intentarás activar un elemento que aún no existe. Mejor quitar el uso de jQuery, y todo ese bloque junto con la función startup.

Si quieres visualizar los dos primeros KML que tienes listados, no le pongas `preserveViewport` porque el mapa quedará donde mismo y el KML se encenderá en un lugar al otro lado del mundo.

```js
var map;

    // lets define some vars to make things easier later
    var kml = {
        a: {
            name: "MPLS/STPL",
            url: "https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=5&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=212971981154994583939.0004b06640255267e038c"
        },
        b: {
            name: "Bicycling Tour Routes",
            url: "https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=4&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=212971981154994583939.0004902a1824bbc8c0fe9"
        },
        c: {
            name: "areas verdes",
            url: "kml/areas_verdes.kml"
        }
        // keep adding more if ye like 
    };


    // initialize our goo
    function initializeMap() {
        var options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.4488897, -70.6692655),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);
        createTogglers();
    };
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);

    // the important function... kml[id].xxxxx refers back to the top 
    function toggleKML(checked, id) {
        if (checked) {

            var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kml[id].url, {
                preserveViewport: false,
                suppressInfoWindows: true
            });
             
            // store kml as obj
            kml[id].obj = layer;
            kml[id].obj.setMap(map);
        } else {
            kml[id].obj.setMap(null);
            delete kml[id].obj;
        }

    };

    // create the controls dynamically because it's easier, really
    function createTogglers() {

        var html = "<form><ul>";
        for (var prop in kml) {
            html += "<li id=\"selector-" + prop + "\"><input type='checkbox' id='" + prop + "'" +
                " onclick='highlight(this,\"selector-" + prop + "\"); toggleKML(this.checked, this.id)' \/>" +
                kml[prop].name + "<\/li>";
        }
        html += "<li class='control'><a href='#' onclick='removeAll();return false;'>" +
            "Remove all layers<\/a><\/li>" +
            "<\/ul><\/form>";

        document.getElementById("toggle_box").innerHTML = html;
    };

    // easy way to remove all objects
    function removeAll() {
        for (var prop in kml) {
            if (kml[prop].obj) {
                kml[prop].obj.setMap(null);
                delete kml[prop].obj;
            }

        }
    };

    // Append Class on Select
    function highlight(box, listitem) {
        var selected = 'selected';
        var normal = 'normal';
        document.getElementById(listitem).className = (box.checked ? selected : normal);
    };
```

```css
#map_canvas {
width:100%;
height:400px;
}
```

```html
 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyAvBQ1Q9FjYfxdWJF6KPmO822RMMbY2w2o"></script>


<div id="toggle_box">

</div>
<div id="map_canvas">

</div>
```